# A value that once contain the right value another time contain NULL in the same Bean

Tags: java, jsf

I have a strange error , in the same bean I'am using the same proprity twice passed from another bean ,in the first case the proprity return the right value ,in the second case is always NULL.
I'am using JSF2

MY JSF:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{ToolsKPI.myChoice}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{ToolsKPI.getMyListKPI()}" />
         <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="f1,f2,f3"
            listener="#{TestAjax.selectChangeHandler}"></p:ajax>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**My bean:**

```
public class TestAjax implements Serializable{
   **private String myChoice**; //getters+seetters

 public void selectChangeHandler() {   //in this case myChoice contain the right value
  form1Visible = false;
  form2Visible = false;
  form3Visible = false;

  if (this.myChoice.equals("Number Of Issues in Status"))
  {    System.out.println("kpi------"+this.myChoice);
     form1Visible = true;

  }
  else if (this.myChoice.equals("Response Time"))
     form2Visible = true;
  else if (this.myChoice.equals("Number of Issue between to Status"))
     form3Visible = true; 
}





public String CreateQueryNumber()
{
Iterator it= selectedItemscheckbox.iterator();
  Iterator it2= selectedItemscheckbox.iterator();
      String grouping="";
       String selecting="";
      String group="";


while(it.hasNext())
{
 selecting=selecting +","+it.next().toString();  
 System.out.println("selecting---"+ selecting);
}

while(it2.hasNext())
{
 grouping=grouping+it2.next().toString()+",";
 System.out.println("grouping---"+ grouping);
}

 int endString =grouping.length()-1;
 group= grouping.substring(0,endString) ;
 **System.out.println("choice"+this.getMyChoice()); //in this case it's NULL!!!!!**

 try{
   if (myChoice.equals("Number Of Issues in Status"))
   {  
      System.out.println(myChoice);

    select ="select count(jiraissue.id) as nb "+selecting;
   from =" from  jiraissue ,priority  ,project,issuestatus  ";
   where=" where jiraissue.project=project.id ";
   jointure=" and jiraissue.issuestatus=issuestatus.id and jiraissue.priority =priority.id and issuestatus.pname="+"'"+this.getMyChoiceStatus()+"' ";
   groupBy=" group by "+group;
   sql =select+from+where+jointure+groupBy+" ;";

            return sql;
 }

   if(myChoice.equals("Response Time"))
    System.out.println(myChoice);
   {
   select ="select AVG(jiraissue.id) as nb "+selecting;
   from =" from  jiraissue ,priority  ,project,issuestatus  ";
   where=" where jiraissue.project=project.id ";
   jointure=" and jiraissue.issuestatus=issuestatus.id and jiraissue.priority =priority.id and issuestatus.pname="+"'"+this.getMyChoiceStatus()+"' ";
   groupBy=" group by "+group;
   sql =select+from+where+jointure+groupBy+" ;";
    System.out.println("sqlKPI2"+sql);
    return sql;

}
```

}

**FacesConfig**

```
<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>TestAjax</managed-bean-name> 
<managed-bean-class>DAOKPI.TestAjax</managed-bean-class> 
<managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>myChoice</property-name>
   <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
   <value>#{ToolsKPI.myChoice}</value>
 </managed-property>   
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Can you include the getters and setters for the myChoice field? The time when it works you're using this.myChoice (the field itself) and the time that it doesn't work you're using this.getMyChoice() (the getter for the field) - the problem may be with your getter, though how you'd mess that up I don't know.

Comment: @Anthony Grist ,I have tried this.myChoice in the second time and the same problem persist :(

Comment: hello @Odelya ,I'am using JSF2

Answer (score 0):

Declare your bean as view in the scope like this:

```
<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>TestAjax</managed-bean-name> 
<managed-bean-class>DAOKPI.TestAjax</managed-bean-class> 
<managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>myChoice</property-name>
   <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
   <value>#{ToolsKPI.myChoice}</value>
 </managed-property>   
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: I have changed the bean to view but the following error appear :  com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanPreProcessingException: Erreur inattendue lors du traitement du bean géré TestAjax